Product Shows as In Stock Despite Salable Quantity Being 0 in Default Stock - Magento MSI Issue
I'm currently facing an issue with Magento Multi-Source Inventory (MSI). For products under the Default Stock, the salable quantity reaches 0, but the product still displays as "In Stock" on the storefront. This issue is affecting inventory management and customer experience, as items appear purchasable even when out of stock.
Here are some details of our setup:
We are using Magento MSI (Multi-Source Inventory).
The problem only occurs with Default Stock; other custom stocks are working fine.
Magento version: 2.4.2
What I've Tried So Far:
Reindexing and clearing the cache.
Reviewing the product stock configuration and source assignment.
Checking the "Backorders" setting to ensure it is disabled.
Questions:
Is there a known bug or configuration setting in MSI that could cause this behavior specifically in the Default Stock?
Are there any recommended troubleshooting steps or code adjustments to make sure that products display as "Out of Stock" when salable quantity reaches 0?
Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

did you check the backorders setting on the product to see if that's enabled?

we have fixed this issue after applying this fix
https://github.com/magento/inventory/pull/3349
